# Wordpress login just refreshes for multiple user manager plugins

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a wordpress website with a simple user manager function
The theme I'm using is [astra premium](https://wordpress.org/themes/astra/) with [elementor pro](https://elementor.com/pro/)
I've tried

1. [profile builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/) plugin and there was an issue -> the login page just refreshes after working good about few weeks. it says in the url

> wppb_cpm_redirect

2. [ultimate member](https://ultimatemember.com/) the login page redirects to the page I've given, but still not logged in when go and check the login page
3. [User Registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/) just refreshes the login page, not logging in
4. [WP User Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-manager/) same here, just refreshes

Please give me a solution to this issue, I tried many things reading many forums, nothing worked so far ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer of [WP User Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-manager/) here .

Is your issue that the login form doesn't actually login you in - and just refreshes. Or when you login it doesn't redirect you to the correct page after login?

If it is the first case, I would recommend testing with a default Twenty theme activated, [enable WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to see if any errors are occurring.

If it is the second case, WP User Manager can have a page set to redirect to after login (in Users > Settings > Redirects). But by default, if will redirect to the same page after login, unless the user has tried to access a restricted page, then clicked login from it. They will be redirected to the restricted page after login.

Comment: The issue I'm having is when a user login it just refreshes. I have a good idea about the redirection futures in wp user manager plugin. This is not a redirection. I'll try enabeling wp debug. thank you !

Comment: Great. Feel free to [send me a message](https://wpusermanager.com/contact/) if you need further help